# How to pass parameter from child model window to parent viewModel

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

**Use-Case**
Open a pop-up window on an click event in a viewModel with some param so that related data could be loaded in the pop-up. Now get the selected data-models from the pop-up window and return those params back to the parent view mode.

**Issue**

1. I am not able to get the params from that model window but can pass params to model window.
2. Correct me if I am wrong, model window would have it's on View-Model/composer associated with it and it will handle all the actions locally.

In short, when I close the window, I want to have selected/data, or ListModel in my parent viewmodel, without creating it again using following line of code, because it doesn' go with my use case, I have to keep the layout as it is after closing the model pop-up window

```
Executions.createComponents(MODEL_WINDOW_PAGE, null, map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see example how can we do this ..Let us suppose

```
    public void createReorderModal(Component comp) {
    Map args = new HashMap();
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("test");
    args.put("availableList", list );
    Executions.getCurrent().createComponents("/core/component/model_window.zul",comp, args);

        }
```

Now in **model_window.zul** have a own ViewModel ,now in this viewmodel's afterCompose method write below code,to get argument passed in previous step.

```
@AfterCompose
public void doAfterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view,
            @ExecutionArgParam("availableList")   List list) {
//Your Business logic
}
```

Now how you will pass the data from child modal Window to main Window , for that you have create a button in your child Window like this.

```
<button onClick="@command('doSort')" type="button" label="Sort" />
```

Now in this **doSort()** method do this logic..

```
    @Command
    public void doSort(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            List someData = new ArrayList();
            someData.add(Add some Data which you send back);
            params.put("orderBySelection", someData);

            Binder bind = (Binder) view.getParent().getAttribute("binder");
            if (bind == null)
                return;
            bind.postCommand("doColumnSorting", params);

            view.detach();
    }
```

Now you will check this line of code..

```
bind.postCommand("doColumnSorting", params);
```

this line will do magic for you .this line will call Parent View Modal Method and now you are in parent viewmodel class and change the respected value and NotifyChange it. May be this will help you

Comment: i am working on it, thanks for your help, hope it will solve my problem.

Comment: my model window is not being poped up. in logs i can see my passed parameter in poped up window. I am calling Excutue in On_Drop event. otherwise it's working properly

Comment: i did not get your problem can you explain bit more?

Comment: i am getting nullPOintedException for this statement in doSort Method.             Binder bind = (Binder) view.getParent().getAttribute("binder"); actually view.getParent is null.

Comment: Is your childwindow have any parent

Comment: I am afraid not, how to do that, in your reference, i tried "this" but it didn't worked and should I have any zul component as it's parent, I am afraid that I didn't get it completely

Comment: As Per you:- Open a pop-up window on an click event in a viewModel .If it is right you are opening a modal window when you click somewhere in Parent Modal Window if this is the case then bove solution will perfectly work

Comment: ok, i got this, but now i am getting this exception: cannot find any method that is annotated for the command cId with @Command in demo.tree.view.TreeModelView ????? But i have @Command("doColumnSorting")
 public void doColumnSorting(@BindingParam("cId") String cId){..] this method in my target file

Comment: may be you are calling cld from your bid.postCommad() method..This exception mean in some command calling name have any issue

Comment: excellent, thanks for the help, my basic use case is working now.